# Which of the following codes would be more practical, feasible, and fast? C#

Tags: c#, winapi, api, compare

Both of these methods work correctly, but I was wondering which of them is "better"? Either best practices, less bug prone or faster?

**Method 1:**

```
    public static ListViewItem[] GetProcessData()
    {
        ManagementClass MgmtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
        ListViewItem[] ProcessItems = new ListViewItem[MgmtClass.GetInstances().Count - 2];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (ManagementObject Processes in MgmtClass.GetInstances())
        {
            if (!Processes["Name"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("system"))
            {
                string[] ProcessInfo = { Processes["Name"].ToString(), Processes["ProcessId"].ToString() };
                ProcessItems[i] = new ListViewItem(ProcessInfo);
                i++;
            }
        }

        return ProcessItems;
    }
```

**Method 2:**

```
    public static ListViewItem[] GetProcessData()
    {
        Process[] PInfo = Process.GetProcesses();
        ListViewItem[] ProcessItems = new ListViewItem[PInfo.Length - 2];
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < PInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!PInfo[i].ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("system") & !PInfo[i].ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("idle"))
            {
                string[] ProcessInfo = { PInfo[i].MainModule.ModuleName, PInfo[i].Id.ToString() };
                ProcessItems[j] = new ListViewItem(ProcessInfo);
                j++;
            }
        }

        return ProcessItems;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking them yourself? That would seem like the most obvious thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, i had compared, but... i just want the opinion of another people, excuse if this annoy you! ¬¬

Comment: I think this is a legit question. Yes, you can benchmark one solution versus another on one machine, and then find out that it works absolutely differently on another machine. So Krähne wants to know if there are advantages of using one approach vs another.

Comment: @Alex Aza: True, I just would have like to have seen that in the original question. I removed the -1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Process class as a typed approach. A little less bug prone in this case:

```
public static ListViewItem[] GetProcessData()
{
    return Process.GetProcesses()
        .Where(arg => arg.Id != 0 && !arg.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("system"))
        .Select(arg => new ListViewItem(new[] { arg.MainModule.ModuleName, arg.Id.ToString() }))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Wow... you're like a genius!

I have modified and now works perfectly!

Thank you dude!.